# segmentation fault when trying to access an element of the array because array values doesn't change after passing them to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, graphics

I am trying to read a ply file and create a Object3D object using [RPly library](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/rply/). I set callback methods to properties. I passed the address of the array to the ply_set_read_cb so I can access and modify it when I read the file. It seems to work alright in the callback function(vertex_cb) as can be seen in the output but when I try to access an element of vlist like vlist[0].x, I get segmentation error. What might be the reason?

Here is my code:

Object3D.cpp

```
#include "Object3D.h"
#include "rply.h"
enum VertexProperty {x,y,z,r,g,b};
int Object3D::i_vertex=0;
int Object3D::i_triangle=0;
int Object3D::i_triangle_vert=0;
int Object3D::vertex_cb(p_ply_argument argument) {
    long propVal;
    void* a_list;
    float val = ply_get_argument_value(argument);
    ply_get_argument_user_data(argument, &a_list, &propVal);
    Vertex* list = (Vertex*) a_list;
    switch (propVal)
    {
    case VertexProperty::x:
        list[i_vertex].x = val;
        break;
    case VertexProperty::y:
        list[i_vertex].y = val;
        break;
    case VertexProperty::z:
        list[i_vertex].z = val;
        break;
    case VertexProperty::r:
        list[i_vertex].r = val;
        break;
    case VertexProperty::g:
        list[i_vertex].g = val;
        break;
    case VertexProperty::b:
        list[i_vertex].b = val; 
        printf("vertex %d: x: %f y: %f z:%f\n", i_vertex, list[i_vertex].x, list[i_vertex].y, list[i_vertex].z);
        i_vertex ++;
        break;
    }
    return 1;
}

int Object3D::triangle_cb(p_ply_argument argument) {
    long length, value_index, propVal;
    void* b_list;
    int val = ply_get_argument_value(argument);
    ply_get_argument_user_data(argument, &b_list, &propVal);
    ply_get_argument_property(argument, NULL, &length, &value_index);
    Triangle* list = (Triangle*) b_list;
    switch (value_index) {
        case -1:
            i_triangle_vert = 0;
            list[i_triangle].nverts = val;
            list[i_triangle].verts = (int*) malloc(val * sizeof(int));
            break;
        case 0:
            list[i_triangle].verts[i_triangle_vert++] = val;
            break;
        case 1:
            list[i_triangle].verts[i_triangle_vert++] = val;
            break;
        case 2:
            list[i_triangle].verts[i_triangle_vert] = val;
            printf("Triangle no:%d, vertices: %d %d %d\n", i_triangle, list[i_triangle].verts[0],list[i_triangle].verts[1],list[i_triangle].verts[2]);
            i_triangle ++;
            break;
    }

    return 1;
}

void Object3D::CreateObject(const std::string& ply_file_path)
{
    p_ply ply;
    i_vertex=0;
    i_triangle=0;
    i_triangle_vert = 0;

    char* c_file = (char*)ply_file_path.c_str();
    ply = ply_open(c_file, NULL, 0, NULL);
    // read the header/file format
    ply_read_header(ply);

    vertexCount = ply_set_read_cb(ply, "vertex", "x", vertex_cb, &vlist, VertexProperty::x);
    ply_set_read_cb(ply, "vertex", "y", vertex_cb, &vlist, VertexProperty::y);
    ply_set_read_cb(ply, "vertex", "z", vertex_cb, &vlist, VertexProperty::z);
    ply_set_read_cb(ply, "vertex", "r", vertex_cb, &vlist, VertexProperty::r);
    ply_set_read_cb(ply, "vertex", "g", vertex_cb, &vlist, VertexProperty::g);
    ply_set_read_cb(ply, "vertex", "b", vertex_cb, &vlist, VertexProperty::b);
    triangleCount = ply_set_read_cb(ply, "triangle", "vertex_indices", triangle_cb, &tlist, 0);
    Vertex v[vertexCount];
    Triangle t[triangleCount];
    vlist = v;
    tlist = t;
    printf("vertices: %d, triangles: %d\n", vertexCount,triangleCount);
    ply_read(ply);
    free(ply);

    for(int i=0; i<vertexCount; i++){ 
            printf("this is v[%d].x = %f\n",i, vlist[i].x); //HERE I GET SEGFAULT 
    }
//other stuff
}
```

Object3D.h

```
#pragma once

#include "glad.h"
#include <string>
#include "GeometricDefinitions.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include "rply.h"


class Object3D
{
private:
    static int i_vertex;
    static int i_triangle;
    static int i_triangle_vert;
public:
    GLuint VBO;
    GLuint EBO;
    GLuint VAO;
    GLuint texture;
    int vertexCount;
    int triangleCount;
    glm::mat4 modelMatrix;
    Vertex* vlist;
    Triangle* tlist;

    Object3D();
    ~Object3D();

    void CreateObject(const std::string& ply_file_path);
    static int vertex_cb(p_ply_argument argument);
    static int triangle_cb(p_ply_argument argument);
};
```

definitions.h

```
#pragma once


struct Vertex {
    float x, y, z;             /* the usual 3-space position of a vertex */
    float r, g, b;             // Color

    //Don't forget to modify this method if you are to change the vertex structure.
    void getAsArray(float* attributeArray)
    {
        //Keep the declaration order
        attributeArray[0] = x;
        attributeArray[1] = y;
        attributeArray[2] = z;
        attributeArray[3] = r;
        attributeArray[4] = g;
        attributeArray[5] = b;
    }
};

struct Triangle {
    int nverts;    /* number of vertex indices in list */
    int* verts;              /* vertex index list */
};
```

Output:

```
vertices: 4, triangles: 2
vertex 0: x: -0.500000 y: -0.500000 z:0.000000
vertex 1: x: -0.500000 y: 0.500000 z:0.000000
vertex 2: x: 0.500000 y: 0.500000 z:0.000000
vertex 3: x: 0.500000 y: -0.500000 z:0.000000
Triangle no:0, vertices: 0 1 2
Triangle no:1, vertices: 0 2 3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I use g++ compiler.

Comment: I think you need to focus the question to get help. You can try any of the following concepts to do so: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ : making a  [mre] ; https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You're passing `Vertex**` and `Triangle**` when you register your callbacks, but you're casting to `Vertex*` and `Triangle*` inside them.

Comment: Your variable-length arrays (a non-standard extension) are probably going to cause stack overflows when you start loading data of a non-trivial size, and the `vlist` and `tlist` pointers become invalid when `CreateObject` returns. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: `Vertex v[vertexCount];Triangle t[triangleCount];` -- Don't do this.  Use `std::vector<Vertex> v(vertexCount); std::vector<Triangle> t(triangleCount);`.  Also, you should use more descriptive names other than single-letter variables, such as `t` and `v`.

Comment: Thank you! Using std::vector solved the problem but why should I use std::vector instead of array? Also, I usually use more descriptive words but I was trying a lot of stuff so I used those for now but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not supported in C++ (but variable-length std::vectors are supported)